# why did calling the function inside the class also printed the return type?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, class, object

There is a class Dog and am defining a function bark() inside it, so when I try call this function this way, I am getting the  `"arf"`  but also  `()` . Why is that?  Sorry, I just started Swift and this I didn't understand.

```
class Dog {
    var whatThisDogSays = "woof"
    func bark(){
        print(self.whatThisDogSays)
    }
}
let d = Dog()
d.whatThisDogSays = "arf"
let barkFunction = d.bark
print(barkFunction())

//prints  
//arf
//()
```

Answer (score 3):

When a Swift function doesn't explicitly state a return type, such as your `Dog.bark()` function, then it implicitly returns `Void`, as if it was `func bark() -> Void { ... }`

`Void` is the name of Swift's [*unit type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type), that is, a type with only one possible value. It's another name for `()`, the empty tuple, whose only value is also `()`, which is just an empty tuple.

The statement `print(self.whatThisDogSays)` prints the value of `whatThisDogSays` (`"woof"` of type `String`).

Then `print` prints the return value of `barkFunction()`, which is `()`, the empty tuple, of type `()` a.k.a. `Void`.

Comment: now it make sense, my function doesn't return a value so swift made sure and typed that yes that's the <code>print </code> value but there is no return value so take this <code> () </code>. Thanks a lot, Alexander.

Comment: You can use backticks in comments to format code `like this`. I didn't really understand what you said, but technically, almost all Swift functions return *do* value. They return the empty tuple. Without an explicit return type, they act as if they have `-> Void` in their signature, and have `return ()` at the end before the `}` (and every plain `return` keyword acts like `return ()`).